# Table X has no column named Y (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite

This is the database handling part of a longer Python program:

```
dbcon = lite.connect('spcbase.db')  # Connects to database file spcbase.db.
cur=dbcon.cursor()                  # Creates database cursor.
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spectrum(spectrumID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, seriesID INTEGER, scan_ang DECIMAL, Path TEXT)")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS series(seriesID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date DATE, gpsx DECIMAL, gpsy DECIMAL, colprec DECIMAL, refangle DECIMAL)")
    # Executes SQL-query that will create one table of spectrums
    # and one table over series of measurements, should these
    # tables or this database not exist.
with dbcon:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO series(date, gpsx, gpsy, colprec, refangle) VALUES(CURRENT_DATE, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [AP[0], AP[1], 6, refangle])
cur.execute("SELECT MAX(seriesID) FROM series")
current_series = cur.fetchone()[0]
src = u'.\\MaestroData'
dest = u'.\\target'
files=getspc(src)
i=0
for mfile in files:
    oldpath=os.path.normpath(os.path.join(src,mfile))
    print "oldpath: ", oldpath
    newpath=os.path.normpath(os.path.join(dest,mfile))
    print "newpath", newpath
    os.rename(oldpath,newpath)
    with dbcon:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO spectrum(seriesID, scan_ang, Path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [current_series, scan_dirs[i], newpath])
    i=i+1
dbcon.close()
```

When run it gets the error "Operational error: table spectrum has no column scan_ang", despite declaring such a column only a few lines above. What is wrong?

Comment: You said `IF NOT EXISTS`. Might there be an existing table without that column?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to commit:

```
dbcon.commit()
```

Only then any modifying queries will actually take place.

Comment: Where should I put this? When whould i use "with dbcon:"? It has struck me that I use it rather whimsicaly.

Comment: You should put this after you've made any changes to the database (after any insert, delete, alter, etc. queries). The database is locked by default, and even though the changes have been made, the connection object (dbcon) has no access to the new data.

Comment: Besides, if you put it anywhere in your code (ofc after declaring the dbcon variable), the database will be permanently updated, and even if it doesn't work at the 1st time, it certainly WILL next time you run the code.